# how to edit ephemeral messages in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

```py
@slash.command(
  name = 'create', 
  description = 'Start a new giveaway ',
  guild_ids = guild,
  options = [
    Option(
      'title',
      'Enter title of the giveaway',
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = True),
    Option(
      'lenght' , 
      'how long will the giveawayrun for? (for example: 3w 4d 5h 6m 7s)',
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = True),
    Option(
      'channel' , 
      'Where should the giveaway be?',
      OptionType.CHANNEL,
      required = False),
    Option(
      'winners' , 
      'How many winners?',
      OptionType.INTEGER,
      required = False),
    Option(
      'description' , 
      'Give your giveaway some extra info.',
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = False),
    Option(
      'win_message' , 
      'Send this private message to the winners',
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = False),
    Option(
      'color' , 
      'Color for the giveaway embed',
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = False,
      choices = [
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'Red',
          value = 'Red'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'Blue',
          value = 'Blue'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'Green',
          value = 'Green'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'white',
          value = 'White'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'no Color',
          value = 'No Color'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'orange',
          value = 'Orange'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'purple',
          value = 'Purple'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'gold',
          value = 'Gold'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'teal',
          value = 'Teal'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'burple',
          value = 'Burple'
        ),
        OptionChoice(
          name = 'random',
          value = 'Random'
        )]),
    Option(
      'image' , 
      'Image link to displayin the embed.',
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = False),
    Option(
      'emoji' , 
      "The emoji to use for the giveaway reaction. (make sure it's from this guild!!)",
      OptionType.STRING,
      required = False)
  
  ])


@commands.has_role(config['giveaway_role'])
async def _create(ctx, title:str , lenght:str , desc = None , emoji ='<a:830767975124041768:910461912133804073>' , winners = 1):

  tm = convert(lenght)
  if tm == -1:
    await ctx.send('Invalid argument: ``length``')
    return
  elif tm == -2:
    await ctx.send('Invalid argument: ``length``')
    return
  time = sec(tm)
  print(time)
  embed = discord.Embed(title = "Create a new giveaway!" , description = '')
  embed.add_field(name = 'Basic Settings' ,
  value = f'''<:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>**Title**: {title}
    <:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>**Description**: {desc}
    <:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>**Lenght**: {time}
    <:878677713269968896:909470525108154399>**Emoji**: {emoji}
    <:878677686350934027:910454682219085834>**Winners**: {winners}''')
  embed.add_field(name = "Requirements" , value="``No Requirements yet``" , inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name = "Multipliers" , value="``No Multipliers yet``" , inline = False)
  embed.set_footer(text='Must meet all requirments')
  row_of_buttons = ActionRow(
      Button(
          style=ButtonStyle.gray ,
          label="Add Req.",
          custom_id="add_req",
          emoji='➕'),
      Button(
          style=ButtonStyle.gray,
          label="Add Mult.",
          custom_id="add_mult",
          emoji='➕'))

  columns_of_buttons = ActionRow(
      Button(
          style = ButtonStyle.gray,
          label= "Remove Item",
          custom_id="remove_item",
          emoji='➖'),
      Button(  
          style = ButtonStyle.gray,
          label= "Start",
          custom_id="start",
          emoji='➡'))

  msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed ,components= [row_of_buttons , columns_of_buttons] , ephemeral=True)

  on_click = msg.create_click_listener(timeout=60)

  @on_click.matching_id("add_req")
  async def on_add_req(ctx):
    ActionRow.disable_buttons(row_of_buttons)
    ActionRow.disable_buttons(columns_of_buttons)
    
    embed.title='Add new Requirement'
    embed.description = '**Choose a requirement type**'
    embed.clear_fields()
    embed.set_footer(text='')
 

    await msg.edit(embed = embed , components = [row_of_buttons , columns_of_buttons,
    SelectMenu(
      custom_id="add_req_menue",
      placeholder="Select a requirement type",
      max_values=1,
      options=[
              SelectOption("Account Older",'1', "Must be a certain amount of days old"),
              SelectOption("Member Older", "2" , "Must be a member for a certain amount of days"),
              SelectOption("Role", "3" , "Member must have the specified role"),
              SelectOption("Not Role" ,"4","Member must **not** have the specific role"),
              SelectOption("Messages" , "5" , "Must have sent the specified amount of messages"),
              SelectOption("Badge" , "6" , "Member must have the specified badge"),
              SelectOption("Tag" , "7" , "Member must have the specified operator"),
              SelectOption("Voice Duration" , "8" , "Have been in VC for a certain amount of minutes"),
              SelectOption("Status" , "9", "Member must have the specific status(es)"),
              SelectOption("Bio" , "10" , "Member must have this in their custom status"),
              SelectOption("Name" , "11" , "Member must have this in their name"),
              SelectOption("Activity" , "12" , "Member must meet a specified activity threshold")])],ephemeral=True)
```

I was trying to edit an ephemeral message in discord.py but for some reason, it is showing a 404 not found error, is there any way to fix this?

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-35' coro=<_create.<locals>.on_add_req() done, defined at d:\Giveaway Bot\main.py:210> exception=NotFound('404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Giveaway Bot\main.py", line 220, in on_add_req
    await msg.edit(embed = embed , components = [row_of_buttons , columns_of_buttons,
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\_modifications\old.py", line 225, in edit_with_components  
    data = await message._state.http.edit_message(message.channel.id, message.id, **fields)
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

I have searched about this online and found out that ephemeral messages cannot be edited, but this bot is clearly editing the message, I'm trying to do something similar like this.

[image]

Comment: where are u even getting msg, send full code

Comment: I have edited the code and I am using the slash command

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one, it can help you :

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#Egg=discord.py[voice]
```

This should go to the discord.py repository branch and get the Egg file to install.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, ephemeral messages can only be edited if they were created as [an interaction response](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#create-interaction-response). This can be done via [Edit Original Interaction Response](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#edit-original-interaction-response) endpoint.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31327347)